# Why custom Angular svg cannot be shown?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to display custom SVGs in my Angular material project.

My approach similar to this stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-taqtkq-izuc7e?file=app%2Ficon-svg-example.ts

I have tried several kind of paths and with no luck.

BTW, currently i am running it in dev mode in my local, http://localhost:4200

Answer (score 0):

Found the reason and marked it:

Do not forget to config assets in angular.json:

```
projects: {
    yourProject: {
        architect: {
            build: {
                options {
                        "assets": [
                                "src/assets"
                        ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```